Type error: Parameter 'favorite' implicitly has an 'any' type.when upload to Vercel
I built a nextjs project, its running well in production before I edit somewhere. but after
1.I edit the product detail page, add price ,
2. add a contact form page
3. add a company about us page.
and then facing an error when want to deploy it to vercel.like below.
>  ./utils/actions.ts:261:25
Type error: Parameter 'favorite' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  259 |     },
  260 |   });
> 261 |   return favorites.map((favorite) => favorite.property);
      |                         ^
  262 | };
  263 |
  264 | export const fetchPropertyDetails = (id: string) => {
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1

so I edit it as the instruction of chatgpt.
before it is like as below:
    export const fetchFavorites = async () => {
  const user = await getAuthUser();
  const favorites = await db.favorite.findMany({
    where: {
      profileId: user.id,
    },
    select: {
      property: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          name: true,
          tagline: true,
          country: true,
          price: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return favorites.map((favorite) => favorite.property);
};

after edit:
interface Property {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  tagline: string;
  country: string;
  price: number;
  image: string;
}

export const fetchFavorites = async () => {
  const user = await getAuthUser();
  
  const favorites = await db.favorite.findMany({
    where: {
      profileId: user.id,
    },
    select: {
      property: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          name: true,
          tagline: true,
          country: true,
          price: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  // Use Property interface instead of 'any'
  return favorites.map((favorite: { property: Property }) => favorite.property);
};

after edit it.I already regenerate "npx prisma regenerate". and then push it on .
but still get the error as below:
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
    at new PrismaClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.20.0_prisma@5.20.0/node_modules/.prisma/client/default.js:43:11)
    at 81018 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/297.js:1:27426)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 61298 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/297.js:1:21361)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 78619 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/_not-found/page.js:1:1148)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/_not-found/page.js:1:2580)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/_not-found/page.js:1:2619
    at t.X (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /_not-found
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.13_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

anyone can help?

no matter I use what solution, such as add  "noImplicitAny": false,in tsconfig.json,or add define the type of favorite object by interface, I always face the error : @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.but how, I run npx prisma generate but no result.yours response will be high appreciated.
